# Too many NamedQueries can be a memory problem?

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.1, named-query

Sometimes I think to optimization.

I have a lot of JPA entities, about 100, and their number will increase.

Each entity has at least 3 named query.

I read (but i don't remember where) that the queries are translated and stored as SQL at application's startup.

Now, does will be a cache over-usage having too many named query in my application?

Comment: Too many is relative. If you are looking to optimize, you need to actually measure how much overhead that is to your application, and then evaluate the cost each query is to your resources vs having to create some of those queries on demand over and over. Some may never be used, while others more frequently. Premature optimization can cause real performance issues down the line, so you are better off writing what you need, then looking at the use cases and fixing things to optimize those use cases. 300 queries may be a drop in the resource bucket when you look at the data you load and cache.

Comment: @Chris your comment is the answer! I must pay attention and study what queries are called often and what are called rarely to reduce the stored named queries